# How can I re-configure the root directory in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I have a directory `project name` that contains following folders:

- bin
- doc
- public

The public directory contains the source code. Now I have a test suite that came with the project which requires the eclipse root directory to be the public directory. However when I loaded the project to eclipse I configured `project name` to be the root.

Is there a way to re-configure the eclipse rood directory from `project name` to its subdirectory `public`?

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by 'root' directory. That is not an Eclipse term.

Comment: Thanks for the trouble. I figured it out: needed to import a new project with root `public`. I'll delete the question.

Comment: ah, just read the stack overflow notice. Will not delete the question but answer it so it is closed.

Answer (score 0):

Import the project again to eclipse with `public` as project root directory solves the problem.